# Call a struts2 jsp page from a normal jsp page

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

I have an existing normal jsp web application.
and as per customer requirement i need to create some configuration pages with drop down select boxes. and I have to create this page in Struts 2.
I have created a struts page but I am not able to call this struts2 page from my existing application.

I am getting below error.

```
The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)
    at jsp_servlet.__addprevdn._jsp__tag0(__addprevdn.java:112)
    at jsp_servlet.__addprevdn._jspService(__addprevdn.java:84)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: you can not do that, if you bypass Struts2 filter that framework is not ready to server you and nor the tags, this is also against MVC. Please get your idea clear about how to use struts2

Answer (score 1):

As Umesh Awasthi told, you **can not** do that. You need to know some basics of Struts2.

[image: How Strut2 works]

- First the client request passes through the Servlet container, such as Tomcat. Then the client request passes through a chaining system, which involves three components of Servlet filters.
- In chaining system, first the `HttpServletrequest` goes through the `ActionContextCleanUp` filter. The `ActionContextCleanUp` works with `FilterDispatcher` or [`StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.html) and allows integration with `SiteMesh`.
- Next the `FilterDispatcher` invokes the `ActionMapper` to determine which request should invoke an Action. It also handles execution actions, clean up `ActionContext` and serves static content, like JavaScript files, CSS files, HTML files etc. whenever they are required by various parts of Struts2.
- The `ActionMapper` maps HTTP requests & action invocation requests & vice-versa. The `ActionMapper` may return an action or return null value, if no action invocation request matches.
- When the `ActionMapper` wants that an Action should be invoked, the `ActionProxy` is called by interacting with the `FilterDispatcher`. The `ActionProxy` obtains the Action class & calls the appropriate method. This method consults the framework Configuration Manager, which is initialized from the `struts.xml` file.
- After reading the `struts.xml` file, the `ActionProxy` creates an `ActionInvocation` & determines how the Action should be handled.
- `ActionProxy` encapsulates how an Action should be obtained, & `ActionInvocation` encapsulates how the Action is executed when a request is invoked.
- Then the `ActionProxy` invokes Interceptors with the help of `ActionInvocation`. The main task of Interceptors is to invoke Action by using `ActionInvocation`.
- Once the Action is determined & executed, the result is generated by using `Result` component. The `Result` component look-up data from the Template with the help of Action result code mapped in `struts.xml` The Template may contain JSP, FreeMarker which is used to generate response.

**Note:** The `FilterDispatcher` (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher) is used in the early Struts2 development, and it’s deprecated since Struts 2.1.3.

If you are using Struts version >= 2.1.3, it’s always recommended to upgrade the new filter class – `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter).

Some useful links

1. [apache struts](http://struts.apache.org/)
2. [apache tutorials](http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsTutorials)
3. [How Struts2 works](http://www.javatpoint.com/struts-2-flow)
4. [How Struts2 works](http://www.java4s.com/struts-tutorials/struts-execution-flow-diagram-how-struts-works/)
5. [Difference between FilterDispatcher & StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/difference-between-struts-2-filterdispatcher-and-strutsprepareandexecutefilter/)

Hope this helps.